# Change Font in Menu Buttons (SwiftUI)

Tags: ios, swift, button, swiftui, menu

Hi everyone I'm trying to change the font of the text contained inside a button and a menu but any type of font I use doesn't seem to work ..

When using Menu in swiftUI is it not possible to use change the font of the buttons in the menu?

```
 Menu("Mese") {
     ForEach(months, id:\.self) { month in
        Button(action: { selectedDate = month } ) {
            Text(DateFormatter(format: "MMMM").string(from: month)
            .uppercased())
            .font(.footnote) // Not work .. the font not changed
       }
     }
   }
```

Comment: I know .italic() should work at least..

Comment: @DaWiseguy i tried .bold () and .italic () and it seems there are no differences ... it doesn't work .. when i open the menu its content has the same font and you can't change

Comment: @DaWiseguy doesn't even seem to work .menu Style (myMenu Style ())

Comment: No, you can't change the font. iOS maps these to native controls (i.e., UIMenuItem) that don't support fonts or colors, so anything but Text or Image are discarded.

Comment: if you really in using deferent font, then you should work on custom way

Comment: @swiftPunk no i am using .font (.footnote) and it doesn't work

Comment: I think you misunderstood my last comment.

Comment: @swiftPunk yes I understand forgive me I misinterpreted your suggestion

Comment: No problem, I already made a custom Menu from zero! It is a little tricky to replicate what apple menu does but it is possible